# One WooCommerce Store to multi distributor sites

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I have two Stores on WooCommerce, Store A and Store B.

I want to fetch products and categories to store B from store A so that store B is a sub store of store A, I cannot use MultiSite because store B is on another hosting and It works independently.

I was thinking about creating a plugin that would fetch the data directly through the REST API, but it would take a long time to develop it.

I want to create something like WooCommerce DropShipping (wholesale) provider in store A and WooCommerce DropShipping in store B

Is there any plugin to do these operations or a better way to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Why would it take a long time to fetch the data via the REST API? Whatever data connection/transmission protocol you end up using, you will use one inevitably. If there's a lot of data to transfer, then it's going to take time regardless of how you do it (rest API, or connecting directly to DB A from the PHP at site B, or another method). I think you need to think more about pre fetching/sending and caching data at B, rather than spending much time trying to make small speed improvements in the data transfer.

Comment: what I was talking about was that if I want to develop such a plugin it will take a lot of time, and my main problem is if there or there not such plugin that do these operations.